# CakePHP 2.0 JSHelper Link don't evoke plugin

Tags: tinymce, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to use the JS helper as shown below:

```
echo $this->Js->link(
    'Incluir'
    , array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'add')
    , array(
'title'    => 'Incluir'
, 'update'   => '#content-outer'
, 'before'   => $this->Js->get('#content-outer')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false))
, 'success'  => $this->Js->get('#content-outer')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false))
)
);
```

The result is this ajax and this link below:

```
link: <a href="/bilheteria/events/add" id="link-473478646" title="Incluir">Incluir</a>
ajax: $j("#link-473478646").bind("click", function (event) {$j.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {$j("#content-outer").fadeOut();}, dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$j("#content-outer").fadeIn();$j("#content-outer").html(data);}, url:"\/bilheteria\/events\/add"});
```

The link opens the method requested, using the fade effect, but i have a tinyMCE plugin in this view and it does not render.

When I call a console and execute the call manually the tinyMCE plugins render properly and when I evoke the link using the complete address http://192.168.50.7/bilheteria/events/add the plugins work as well.

I have tried using all of the following options in the js link:

```
method - GET / POST / PUT
type - ‘json’
evalScripts - True / False
```

Why does the the js->link behave in this way? (i.e. rendering the ajax and the link correctly but when the link is used to access the page the tinyMCE plugins are broken?)